# Windows 7 - run program as another user while another instance is already running

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I am logged to some user account on windows seven. I have Firefox running. I would like to run one more instance, but as another user. This doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use multiple FireFox profiles and then launch FF from a command line (or shortcuts) with:

`firefox.exe -p <PROFILE> -no-remote`

More info is available [here](http://www.techspot.com/guides/306-how-to-run-two-firefox-instances/).

You can (also) use this in combination with Windows' [RunAs](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) to get multiple instances actually running as different users.

Hope that helps.